# embed .exe with ordinary file

Tags: c++, c, windows, security

How could I embed or associate an .exe into an ordinary file, like .jpeg or any video etc. 
? I want to associate the opening of the ordinary file with the execution of an executable program.

Comment: Hm, malware 101 ?

Comment: Do you mean you want your program to launch when double-clicking a JPEG? Or you want to stuff your program *into* the JPEG?

Comment: Would you rather have me launch a remote desktop connection to an arbitrary host when i open your jpeg file, or would creating a simple tcp socket suffice? ;)

Comment: @Carl I want the program to launch when I double-click the JPEG. Not stuffed.

Comment: @cnicutar, no malware, just studying the possibilities.

Comment: It's not so easy, you would have to exploit Windows Explorer or whatever displays the image.

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do is **intended** not to be possible. If and when it does happen, it takes place by exploiting a flaw in the program reading the file. This might take place (this is more common when the program is written in C or C++) by storing out-of-range values in the headers and hoping the program does not validate them before using them as offsets in memory, or (this is more common in higher-level languages) by taking advantage of a logical error in some overgrown feature the format intentionally allows (like embedding javascript).

Beyond this, I think any further answer is off-topic on SO. This is not a site for getting help writing malware.

Comment: Then where is that site? haha. joking, no malware here.

Comment: Find the secret elite blackhats channel on irc and ask them to send you their tools. It's a self-extracting archive called "iamafool.exe". :-)

Comment: Haha. You so funny. But thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: @lxClan I'm sorry R is making fun of you. What you're looking for is [here](http://boards.4chan.org/b/). Ask nicely on that board and people will help you.

Comment: I hope that didn't come across as me making fun of OP. From the first comment, it seemed like OP was just kidding about asking for a site, and I assumed OP would appreciate the joke.